# Why does drupal think there is entity data?

Tags: entities, 8

I am working on customizing the poll module for my D8-rc1 site.  I have sufficiently broken the module and would like to uninstall it and try to reinstall an earlier version of my work.  However when i try to uninstall i get this

```
exception 'Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleUninstallValidatorException' with message[error]
'The following reasons prevents the modules from being uninstalled: There is
content for the entity type: Poll' in
/srv/www/dtadev2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php:347
Stack trace:
#0
/srv/www/dtadev2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(95):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array, true)
#1
/home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(227):
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->uninstall(Array)
#2 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/pm_8.inc(80):
drush_module_uninstall(Array)
#3 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1190):
_drush_pm_uninstall(Array)
#4 [internal function]: drush_pm_uninstall('poll')
#5 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(364):
call_user_func_array('drush_pm_uninst...', Array)
#6 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(215):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#7 [internal function]: drush_command('poll')
#8 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(183):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#9 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(62):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#10 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(70):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#11 /home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(11): drush_main()
#12 {main}
```

and all 4 poll tables are totally empty.  when I run an entity query 
it returns

```
array(0) { }
```

so where else is entity information stored that could be hiding some information to make drupal believe there is content for the entity?

Comment: Could it be that there is poll field attached to somewhere or block instance?

Comment: Im going to spend my day combing my content types and views for that.  thanks